# Intents in a browser, is it possible to trigger an intent from Javascript in the Android web browser?

Tags: android, android-intent

Quick question that I can't seem to find an answer for.

If I am in the Android web browser... is it possible to fire a "Share" intent with JavaScript?
Just trying to streamline the "Share to..." process.

It might not be possible but I would just like to confirm it before I announce that to my team.

Added info:

I do not have any Android application running. Only an HTML file and a JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most certainly is possible.  Take a look at the [`WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) method, as it should be able to provide you exactly what you need.

The basics of using `addJavascriptInterface()` are detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript).

1. Create the class that will fire the intent.  This is typically just a standalone class (no need to extend a `Service` or `Activity`).
2. Bind this class to your `WebView` (This would be the `addJavascriptInterface()` call).
3. Call the corresponding method from your Javascript.

Comment: That technically isn't the *Android browser* app. Also, you should be very careful when/if you allow calling the interface from untrusted sites.

Comment: I have only html and js. We can't have java class. Please elaborate.

Comment: This solution only works if you have wrapped your site in a webview app. This does not work for a regular site built with HTML and JS.

Comment: @owencm With a question regarding Android and Android-Intent, I would imagine that they are developing within a `WebView` in Android, and not doing an HTML/JS/CSS site.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild although he does say in the web browser and "I do not have any Android application running", the question also makes sense as asking whether a site can trigger an android intent with JS which is how I read it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the user to a link that your application Activity intent filters are cibling, yes, it is possible.